# is it wrong to use type assertion for error handling?

Tags: go, error-handling

i was wondering why isn't switch + type assertion style error handling more used/recommended in golang. is there anything wrong with it or the community just doesn't care about it ?

for example the code below :

```
if err != nil {
    if errors.As(err, &QueryErr{}) {
        log.Println("query error : ", err)
        return http.StatusInternalServerError
    } else if errors.As(err, &QueryDataExtractionErr{}) {
        return http.StatusNotFound
    } else {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return http.StatusInternalServerError
    }
}
```

could be written as :

```
if err != nil {
    switch err.(type) {
    case QueryErr:
        log.Println("query error : ", err)
        return http.StatusInternalServerError
    case QueryDataExtractionErr:
        return http.StatusNotFound
    default:
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return http.StatusInternalServerError
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type-switch is technically correct. However, the type-swich with errors will misinterpret wrapped errors. For instance:

```
err:=io.EOF
err1 := fmt.Errorf("Unexpected error: %w",err)
```

In the above, `err1.(io.EOF)` will fail, but `errors.Is(err1,io.EOF)` will not.

So you should use `errors.Is` and `errors.As` to test whether the error you have at hand wraps the error you are looking for.

Comment: This should be the %w verb in fmt.Errorf, right?

Comment: @Peter, correct. Fixed.